# IMG max-width 100% rendering issue on IE 11 & EDGE

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I work on a new wordpress website for a local football using a child theme of the Twenty sixteen. As I did a browser control, I saw that MSIE makes a mess of the scaled images (max-with & max-height).

[Rendring issue on MSIE and EDGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDfyz.jpg)

Never before had I noticed this and was wondering if there is a good solution to this problem.

So far I've tried the following, but that did nothing

```
img {-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}
```